# Skype logout (pc logout) when activating the user interface

Tags: skype, emacs

I have a problem with my skype (version 4.2.0.11) , when I open it I instantly logout from computer. I tried to remove (also remove it by using `--purge`) and reinstall from terminal however same problem occurred again. I also tried to open it from terminal but all same.

Same problem occurred with emacs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Joseph R. from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127857/getting-logged-out-of-user-account-upon-execution-of-a-program?noredirect=1#comment204788_127857
You can try launching Skype via the CLI:

```
skype 2>~/skype-err.log &
```

This redirects the standard error to the file name `skype-err.log` under your home directory. Then you can post the contents of this file together with the contents of `~/.xsession-errors` file on this website and the link provided above to seek further help.